# Ionic 3 Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ChatNotificationServiceProvider: (?, ?) when injecting a provider in another provider

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to `inject` a provider (`ChatNotificationServiceProvider`) into my `AuthService` (Another provider), however when I `inject` the ChatNotificationServiceProvider into my AuthService provider (via the constructor), the error '**Can't resolve all parameters for ChatNotificationServiceProvider: (?, ?)**' appeared.

I have read other solutions and they all said to put the `@Injectable` in the `ChatNotificationServiceProvider` and it should work. However, I have already put in the `@Injectable` but it still does not work.

Here are my codes:
ChatNotificationServiceProvider.ts

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth-service/auth-service';

@Injectable()
export class ChatNotificationServiceProvider {

  public chat;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
}
```

AuthService.ts

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import 'firebase/auth'
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/storage';
import { ChatNotificationServiceProvider } from '../chat-notification-service/chat-notification-service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(public listingProvider: ListingProvider, public chatNotificationSvc: ChatNotificationServiceProvider) <-- After injecting the ChatNotificationServiceProvider, the error mentioned above is thrown to me.
{
   this.chatNotificationSvc.str = "Test string";
}
```

Some additional information: I have injected the ChatNotificationServiceProvider in my app.component using the same method and it works fine. Not sure why I can't inject the same provider in the other providers.

Please help! Is it not possible to inject a provider in another provider? I'm quite lost on this.

Edit: Here is my providers in my app.module.ts as requested by @Serena.

```
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    FirestoreServiceProvider,
    AngularFirestore,
    PayPal,
    ChatNotificationServiceProvider,
    Storage, 
    Camera,
    AuthService,
    BookingService,
    ListingProvider,
  ]
```

Comment: First of all, how are you injecting ChatNotificationServiceProvider? Are you adding ChatNotificationServiceProvider to the providers list in the same module that AuthService is registered?
For any service to be used, it needs to be registered in the appropriate module.

Comment: @Serena I have added in my providers in my app.module.ts into the question for reference. Can you see any issues with that?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove

```
import { AuthService } from '../auth-service/auth-service';
```

from ChatNotificationServiceProvider

Also please check the below

To create providers
first.provider.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class FirstProvider {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

second.provider.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SecondPrivider{
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

index.ts

```
export { FirstProvider} from './providers/first.provider';
export { SecondProvider} from './providers/second.provider';
```

in app.module.ts
Please add the above providers

```
providers: [
  FirstProvider,
  SecondProvider
]
```

To create services

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FirstProvider, SecondProvider } from './providers';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private firstProvider: FirstProvider, 
              private secondProvider : SecondProvider ) { }
  onChangeFormat(str) {
      // add logic here
      // this.firstProvider()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! My second provider is the AuthService though, how do I go about doing that? Other than that, I've checked the things you mentioned and I've already implemented it before.